# How can I grab the data from the checkbox in MUI datatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass on an array from the checked values to another table to display only the checked values. How would I go about this?

I'm very new to using react and I just don't fundamentally understand how some of these functions and components work. If checkbox is returned, how would I be able to gather information from it?

```
  import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridValueGetterParams } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
  { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
  { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
  {
    field: 'age',
    headerName: 'Age',
    type: 'number',
    width: 90,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params: GridValueGetterParams) =>
      `${params.row.firstName || ''} ${params.row.lastName || ''}`,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
];

export default function DataTable() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[code is from MUI's site]

Answer (score 0):

add onSelectionModelChange prop callback, see here for details https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/